# Should power of lens be dimensionless quantity?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, units, lenses

My [book](https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/leph201.pdf) defines the power of lens using this way:

> The power P of a lens is defined as the
> tangent of the angle by which it converges or diverges a
> beam of light falling at unit distant from the optical centre $tan(x)=h/f$ and for small $x$ , $x=h/f$ , $h=1, x=1/f$.                           Thus power p of a lens is $p=1/f$.

> The SI unit for power of a lens is dioptre (D): $1D = 1m^{–1}$. The power of
> a lens of focal length of 1 metre is one dioptre. Power of a lens is positive
> for a converging lens and negative for a diverging lens. Thus, when an
> optician prescribes a corrective lens of power $+ 2.5 D$, the required lens is
> a convex lens of focal length $+ 40 cm$. A lens of power of $– 4.0 D$ means a
> concave lens of focal length $– 25 cm$.

If power P of a lens is defined as a tangent of angle of convergence or divergence , the tangent is a dimensionless quantity! So its unit should not be $m^{-1}$ or $D$. Taking h=1 does not mean we negate its dimension right ?

Comment: Please consider using text instead of pictures, pictures get broken or lost in the internet very easily.

Comment: Okay , just give me a few minutes  @Mauricio

Answer (score 1):

Power is not the tangent of an angle. That would indeed be dimensionless.

$P = 1/f$, where $f$ is in meters. Thus the dimension of $p$ is $m^{-1}$.

Comment: Then the definition given in the book shouldn't be taken seriously, have they given it for intuitive purposes ?

Comment: The book is being a little loose, saying $h=1$ and then ignoring $h$. Actually $P = tan(\theta)/h$.